# How can I watch a file system directory to see when files are added to it?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0

In c# winforms application, I want to choose a directory from network and after that, when any body put a file in it, I want to see a message such as "A file added."

for example I can get filepaths.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.bmp");
```

should I run this code 5 minutes later and should I check the differences?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class and subscribe for different events happening on the file system such as files and folders being created, deleted, modified, ...

Comment: For the file which is placed in local area network, is it possible?