# C# console app that checks if new folders exists

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I watch a file system directory to see when files are added to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593955/how-can-i-watch-a-file-system-directory-to-see-when-files-are-added-to-it)

I am creating a console app in c# which one of its functionality is to scan a fix folder path(example c:\FixedFolderA) say every minute and check if a new folders has been created(Example c:\FixedFolderA\NewFolderB).

So several folders will be created under c:\FixedFolderA.

The new folders will have no subdirectories, just files which I will copy to other locations.

I am not sure of the  most efficient design to do this and need your help.

I was thinking of this workflow:

1. Scan c:\FixedFolderA at the start of the program.
2. Store all the sub directories in a list.
3. Create a worker process that scans c:\FixedFolderA and check to see if that sub-directory exists in the list. If the directory doesn't exist perform some action.

My concern is that the umber of sub-directories in c:\FixedFolderA  will increase overtime and the program would be traversing all these directories every minute.

Should the routine to check every minute be done with a process?

Can someone please share your ideas with the best design to get me started ?

Thanks .

Comment: Put the scan in a `Thread` and it should work smoothly.
Although I don't know what exactly your question is.

Comment: You might want to check out [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

Comment: Yes this would be a duplicate . I think filesystemwatcher is my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to watch a folder for changes, use the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class.

Also, if this console application performs a specific task on its own, perhaps it is best to turn it into a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's almost always better to be notified when an event occurs rather than having to query periodically.

For the context you're describing you can very easily use the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class to specify what kind of files you want to be notified about and in which directory you wish to monitor. I put together the following code for you:

```
FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher("C:\\Users\\ByteBlast\\Desktop", "*.*")
{
    EnableRaisingEvents = true, 
    IncludeSubdirectories = true,
    NotifyFilter =  NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
};

fileWatcher.Created += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("{0} Created", eventArgs.FullPath);
```

Where I specify the path to my desktop, you will specify for example, `C:\FixedFolderA`.

You can make sure that you are notified about changes in sub directories by enabling the `IncludeSubDirectories` property like I did above.

Because you're only interested in folders and not files I set the `NotifyFilter` property to `NotifyFilters.DirectroyName`.

Place the code above in your Console Application's `void Main()` and ensure you stop the console from closing by for example including the following statement beneath the code above `Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit();`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than scanning the directory every minute, you should take a close look at [File System Watcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).  This will tell you when a change has been made to the directory structure - thus it will be far more efficient.  Your program just has to keep track for what changes have been made.